# Why Zend_Route don't work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

```
routes.info.route = "info"
routes.info.defaults.module = "default"
routes.info.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.info.defaults.action = "info"

http://localhost/info/ 
Exception information:

    Message: Invalid controller specified (info)

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'info',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

Comment: Thats it?  config.ini and exception

Comment: i guess you dont have a faq controller

Comment: I am trying to route it to index controller

Comment: aha then it is easy try routes.info.defaults.action = "index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the name of second route

```
routes.info.route = "info"
routes.info.defaults.module = "default"
routes.info.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.info.defaults.action = "faq"
```

Comment: actually had to make the configs `resources.router.route.x`